# Does the Eee Pad Transformer TF101 support the APT-X audio codec?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I am considering buying a Bluetooth speaker for use with my Asus Transformer (amongst other devices) but I am unable to find out whether the Transformer supports the APT-X codec, or find any information as to whether this question is actually appropriate as I may be mixing my terms/getting confused.

I am considering a device such as this:

[Creative ZiiSound D5](http://uk.store.creative.com/speakers/ziisound-d5/4-19181.aspx)

What I am wondering is whether the Transformer will be outputting the sound using the APT-X codec or not? Is there any way to determine this?

From the specifications of the Transformer [here](http://uk.asus.com/Eee/Eee_Pad/Eee_Pad_Transformer_TF101/#specifications) the Bluetooth is **Bluetooth V2.1+EDR**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it, since it's proprietary; Android by default only supports [these codecs](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).  It's not required for the speakers to work though, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The speakers will fall back to SBC if the proprietary codec is not available.

Comment: Thanks, my main concern was whether it would be worth justifying the expense of a 'better' set of speakers if the device couldn't actually transmit the music in good enough quality and I think that this answers the question!